# Handling nested frames

Tags: java, selenium, frame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Obir.png)

I am trying to access a frame inside a frame and I tried this code

```
driver.get("https://www.leafground.com/frame.xhtml");
        //frame 1 click and show text
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='Click']"));
        frame1.click();
        
        String frametext = frame1.getText();
        
        System.out.println(frametext);
        
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        //nested frame 
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        driver.switchTo().frame("frame2");
```

But I am getting an error saying "No frame element found by name or id frame2" ;

When I inspect the webpage I could see the frame having id='frame2'.

How should I perform operation on the nested frame?

Comment: 'When I inspect the webpage I could see the frame having id='frame2'.' Well I don't.

Comment: Please copy and paste the HTML, failing that come up with a better image description.

Comment: Post the URL and the full code you've tried.

Comment: Hi, "https://www.leafground.com/frame.xhtml" This is the url that I am trying to automate. and I have updated the code as you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//  Refer below image for result

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(2);  //outer frame
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frame2']")));  // InnerFrame

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='Click']")).click(); // inner frame element

    String msg=driver.findElement(By.id("Click")).getText();
    System.out.println(msg);
```

[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg8Gl.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).